# Jtable- special column

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need create Jtable of column type and value. The value can be true or false or number. That's why I want to show a checkbox or text in one column. Thank you!

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I tried edit column manager. It didn't  work.

Comment: That bit of information doesn't tell us much that we can use, that would make this question more answerable or higher quality. Please tell more and explain more, including showing your [mcve]. Also please read the how-to-ask sections of the [help] as well as [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following give one approach to allowing different data types in the same column:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TablePropertyEditor extends JFrame
{
    public TablePropertyEditor()
    {
        String[] columnNames = {"Type", "Value"};
        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"String", "I'm a string"},
            {"Date", new Date()},
            {"Integer", new Integer(123)},
            {"Double", new Double(123.45)},
            {"Boolean", Boolean.TRUE}
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames)
        {
            private Class editingClass;

            public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column)
            {
                editingClass = null;
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);

                if (modelColumn == 1)
                {
                    Class rowClass = getModel().getValueAt(row, modelColumn).getClass();
                    return getDefaultRenderer( rowClass );
                }
                else
                    return super.getCellRenderer(row, column);
            }

            public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column)
            {
                editingClass = null;
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);

                if (modelColumn == 1)
                {
                    editingClass = getModel().getValueAt(row, modelColumn).getClass();
                    return getDefaultEditor( editingClass );
                }
                else
                    return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
            }

            //  This method is also invoked by the editor when the value in the editor
            //  component is saved in the TableModel. The class was saved when the
            //  editor was invoked so the proper class can be created.

            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                return editingClass != null ? editingClass : super.getColumnClass(column);
            }
        };

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TablePropertyEditor frame = new TablePropertyEditor();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Basically you need to use a renderer/editor based of the data, not the column type.